# Blender does not render the camera view

Tags: rendering

I checked

1. I only have one camera.
2. I have never add any animations.

I cannot figure out why blender renders does not render my camera view.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Solved. Thanks. You can add this to answer section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a cube (and a torus) hidden in your viewport - items hidden in the viewport will still be visible in renders. This is what's blocking your camera view.

[image: Hidden]